# What default/standard fields are there on an Umbraco Node/Document?

Tags: documentation, default, field, umbraco

Due to Umbraco documentation being very.... how should I say.. 'loose'? and split between 'old Umbraco' and 'current Umbraco', I am finding it difficult to find a page that comprehensibly lists all of the standard/default fields of a Node/Document.

I am interested in the current version (4.6.1 at time of writing, using the 'new schema').

Fields such as:

- updateDate
- nodeName
- level

**So, what default/standard fields does every Umbraco Node/Document have?**

EDIT:
OK, so it looks like that is the best answers we're going to get. So using the xslt snippet posted by [forzagaribaldi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215207/what-default-standard-fields-are-there-on-an-umbraco-node-document/5218975#5218975), we have the following list:

- id
- isdoc
- path
- creatorname
- writername
- urlname
- nodename
- updatedate
- createdate
- sortorder
- template
- nodetype
- creatorid
- writerid
- level
- parentid

(Case is wrong for all of these however, e.g. isdoc rather than isDoc)

If anyone can elaborate on this list they will get the tick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get an xml dump of a node by using xslt 'copy-of':

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:copy-of select="$currentPage" />
</xsl:template>
```

Will return all elements and attributes (including nodename, createdate, updatedate, level, etc).